# Backbone dynamic routing, static files won't load

Tags: backbone.js, express, requirejs

I'm having some difficulty with Backbone dynamic routing. I've set up an Express app that serves a Backbone SPA. My routes are configured as follows:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    ...
    'project': 'project',
    'project/:id': 'project',
    ...
  },

  ...

  project: function(id) {
    var projectView = new ProjectView();
    if (id) {
      projectView.render();
    }
    else {
      projectView.render();
    }
  },

  ...

});

var initialize = function(){
  var router = new AppRouter;
  var headerView = new HeaderView();
  var footerView = new FooterView();
  Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true
  });
};
```

Standard routing works perfectly, but when I attempt to visit `http://localhost:5000/project/1`, static files aren't loaded. By looking at the js console, it appears as though the page is looking for the static files at `http://localhost:5000/project/css/...` instead of `http://localhost:5000/css/...`. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Another example: I'm using require.js and my main file is located at `/js/app`. The page attempts to locate the file at `/project/js/app`, which of course, doesn't exist. Has it confused the root url as '/project' instead of '/'? How could I remedy this?

If any other details are needed, let me know. Much thanks.

Comment: It occurred to me that I might need to specify the require.js baseUrl in my config. I set it to '../js' and the problem persists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how things work! It has nothing to do with Backbone.

Solution 1 : (disable pushState)

```
Backbone.history.start({
    //pushState: true
  });
```

this will prevent the browser to relatively look at wrong places for static files, since the URLs will have hash/hashBang suffix for backbone routes.

Solution 2: Use absolute paths for css & js files.

`<link href="http://myexample.com/css/styles.css"/>`

Some Helpful Links

http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/

Answer (score 0):

I guess that backbone routes don't work like that. You'll need to have another function for the 'project/:id'.

Example:

```
routes: {
    ...
    'project': 'project',
    'project/:id': 'projectWithId',
    ...
  },

  ...

  project: function() {

  },

  projectWithId: function(id) {

  },
```

Comment: I attempted to make this change, just as described. The problem still exists. Strange. This problem only occurs with dynamic routes. All other routes work normally.